# remove digits NOT between brackets - regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression in python to remove digits except those between brackets
here is an example : "[Verse 1: Bankroll Fresh] Dope boy, '[9]5 Air Max on Came from 1952.."

I would like : "[Verse 1: Bankroll Fresh] Dope boy, '[9] Air Max on Came from .."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this regex `r'(?<!\[)\d+(?!\])'`?

```py
st = "[Verse 1: Bankroll Fresh] Dope boy, '[9]5 Air Max on Came from 1952.."
st = re.sub(r'\[\D*\d+\D*\]|(?<!\[)\d+(?!\])', lambda x: x.group(0) if x.group(0).startswith('[') else '', st)

# [Verse 1: Bankroll Fresh] Dope boy, '[9] Air Max on Came from ..
print(st)
```

`(?<!\[)` and `(?!\])` are matches if `\d+` NOT preceded by `[` and NOT followed by `]`, respectively.

Comment: thanks, but I also need to keep numbers in parentheses even if they are not directly preceded or followed by parentheses, like [Verse 1: Bankroll Fresh]

Comment: I editted to exclude numbers in parentheses even if they are not directly preceded or followed by parentheses, like [Verse 1: Bankroll Fresh]

Comment: David, I assume when you say "parentheses" you mean "brackets", right?

Comment: Clever idea of discriminating on the basis of the first character of the match!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.

```
import re
 
s = "[Verse 1: Bankroll Fresh] Dope boy, '[9]5 Air Max on Came from 1952.."
 
pattern = r"\[.*?\]|(\d+)"

print(re.sub(pattern, lambda x: '' if x.group(1) else x.group(), s))
  -> [Verse 1: Bankroll Fresh] Dope boy, '[9] Air Max on Came from ..
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/mZOPL6)

The regular expression reads, "Match a left bracket followed by one or more characters matched lazily, followed by a right bracket, or match one or more digits and save the match to capture group 1."

Matching characters lazily prevents a right bracket from being matched. We could alternatively write the first part of the alternation `\[[^\]]*\]`, where `[^\]]*` matches zero or more characters other than a right bracket.

The lambda reads, "If a string has been captured to group 1, replace the match with an empty string; else replace the match with itself".

Note that the order of the alternation is important; `r"(\d+)|\[.*?\]"` will not work.